# como seleccionar el maximo de un campo auto increment y guardarlo en otra tabla

Tags: sql

tengo un registro en una tabla llamada `PARAMETRI` que tiene un campo autoincrement llamado `idparametri`. Lo que quiero hacer es guardar un registro en  una tabla llamada `OBRA`; esa tabla tiene un campo llamado `PARAMETRI_ID_PARAMETRI` y quiero que al hacer un registro me guarde el valor máximo de `ID_PARAMETRI` en `PARAMETRI_ID_PARAMETRI` que es el id de obra, pero a la vez quiero insertar los otros campos de la tabla `OBRA`

Acá se inserta el valor máximo del auto increment a la tabla `OBRA`

```
INSERT INTO OBRA (PARAMETRI_ID_PARAMETRI) SELECT MAX(PARAMETRI.ID_PARAMETRI) FROM PARAMETRI;
```

¿Cómo hago para insertar el máximo valor del auto increment y otros los  parámetros en la tabla `OBRA` que son `NOMBRE_O` ,`DIRECCIÓN` y `VALOR`

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Puedes hacer seguramente on un store procedure, pero depende de que base estes usando sería la forma de implementarlo.

Comment: INSERT INTO obra(id) SELECT MAX(parametrización.idparametri) FROM parametrización;

Comment: SELECT MAX(fiel_name) from table_name

Comment: supongo que ese máximo es el identity, en el caso de sql server puedes utilizar @@IDENTITY, con este podrás obtener el ultimo valor insertado.
[@@IDENTITY MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Agrega el código que hayas tratado @luisasuazua, modifica tu pregunta, revisa [ask]. saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar la inserción incluyendo otros campos, utiliza una sentencia `insert`/`values`, y en el valor del campo `PARAMETRI_ID_PARAMETRI` haces la sub-consulta para obtener el valor máximo que te interesa, por ejemplo:

```
insert into OBRA (NOMBRE_O, DIRECCION, VALOR, PARAMETRI_ID_PARAMETRI) 
values ('Prueba', 'Dirección', 1.0, (select max (ID_PARAMETRI) from PARAMETRI));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me funciono

Comment: De nada, me alegra ser de ayuda. Si mi respuesta te fue de utilidad, considera marcarla como aceptada, eso indicará a futuros navegantes que te fue útil para resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta. Si no sabes bien aún como funciona el sitio, te invito a hacer el [tour].

Comment: @luisa, veo que no has aceptado ninguna de las respuestas que has recibido a tus otras preguntas. Si has encontrado ayuda en ellas, te invito también a aceptarlas. Un saludo.